# Qual o limite de memória do php 7?

Tags: php, memory-limit

Eu li em algum lugar (e agora não estou achando onde) que na versão 7 do php não existe lilmite de memória. Ou seja, a memória que pode ser alocada seria a RAM da máquina. Isso procede? Alguém já leu algo a respeito?

Comment: o limite é a capacidade do hardware.

Comment: vc conseguiu achar onde diz isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo o manual:

> **memory_limit** *integer*
>
> Define a quantidade máxima de memória em bytes
>   que um script está permitido alocar. Isto ajuda a previnir que scripts
>   mal escritos consumam toda memória disponível no servidor. **Note que**
>   **para não ter limite de memória, defina esta diretiva para -1.**

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Já observei que em versões anteriores, o PHP limitava a memória em 4GB, portanto, o máximo que podia alcançar era 4GB - 1MB:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '4095M');
```

Comment: Isso, eu estava preocupado com o fato de um script php7 roubar toda a memória do servidor e prejudicar outros projetos.